# Authentication in Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I know this is very common question. But I really do not know how to integrate it. 
I want to add authentication to my web api services. Right now I have created one console application to call service's method.

I have gone through this [blog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx). I just want to implement authentication filter as mentioned in this article.

I want to know how can I pass credentials along with HTTPClient from my console application, fetch those things to web API and authenticate them.

I have created authentication filter but it does not invoke AuthenticateAsync method of authentication filter.

To pass http client I have done this:

```
 public void GetData()
    {
        HttpClient cons = new HttpClient();
        cons.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:50524/");
        cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ankita:ankita123");
        var header = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(data));
        cons.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = header;

        //MyAPIPost(cons).Wait();
        MyAPIGet(cons).Wait();
    }
```

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/securing-aspnet-web-api--cms-26012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully implemented authentication using [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/18/A-WebAPI-Basic-Authentication-Authorization-Filter#Authorization) article. In that filter attribute is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Teaching you how to implement authentication in Web API will take a lot of time. You better stick to online tutorials.

The blog you've read tackles about different authentication for ASP.NET. Since you've tagged your question as ASP.NET Web API 2, I would suggest using a token-based authentication utilizing OWIN middleware. Check [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/token-based-authentication-in-web-api-2/) out. The guide uses a console application for checking the requests to the web API.

The gist of it is...

Client > Token Provider (Generate token for valid user) > Web API > Check if Token is Valid (Existing and not expired) > Authenticate!

Comment: I need to implement of type attribute. So that we can use it globally or for particular method. Is it possible?

Comment: With Web API you can just tag the method or web api controller with `[Authorize]` attribute if you want to implement authentication. Of course you must implement the provider as shown in the tutorial linked.

Comment: I agree, token based authentication is better than passing passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are trying to access the API with an HttpClient, you can pass it an instance of HttpClientHandler when creating it, which allows you to set the credentials that will be used when it performs requests:

```
new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password) })
```

Hope it helps!